# VB.NET Download file from remote site and manipulate in memory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I have a web service that calls another website which allow me to download an excel file from it.  This has been going good but the users are having problem importing it into an excel file.  I have been tasked to build a web version of it, but I am getting stuck on the utilizing the file myself.

Here is the code snippet where I force the user to download.

```
 Dim fileName As String
    fileName = "test.xls"

    Dim stream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim bytesToRead As Integer = 10000
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New [Byte](bytesToRead - 1) {}

    Try
        Dim fileReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL), HttpWebRequest)
        fileReq.Method = "GET"
        fileReq.CookieContainer = LoginCookie
        fileReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        fileReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB7.5; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)"

        Dim fileResp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(fileReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        If fileReq.ContentLength > 0 Then
            fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength
        End If

        stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream()

        Dim resp = HttpContext.Current.Response
        resp.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & fileName & """")
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString())

        Dim length As Integer
        Do
            If resp.IsClientConnected Then
                length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead)
                resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length)
                resp.Flush()
                buffer = New [Byte](bytesToRead - 1) {}
            Else
                length = -1
            End If
        Loop While length > 0
    Finally
        If stream IsNot Nothing Then
            stream.Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

What I would like to do is instead of resp.Flush, I would like to say something along the line of

Open Test.xls in memory
Read Sheets1.Cells(1,1)
Insert into DB (I have this code)
kill test.xls in memory

Can I do this in memory?

Comment: You can store file under temp name on the server and then open OLEDB connection to it. Then you can run standard SQL queries like SELECT to read data into, say, DataTable, and manipulate any way you want

Comment: Do you have a sample code or link to save the file locally on the server?

Comment: I've put this in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store file under temp name on the server and then open OLEDB connection to it, read the file and delete it. Here's a very basic sample how you can save the file:

Assuming your buffer has the file you read, you can use something like

```
Dim sSafeAsPath = "c:\temp\" & Path.GetRandomFileName
Dim fs = New FileStream(sSaveAsPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

fs.Write(buffer, 0, UBound(buffer))
fs.Close()
```

Note that a random file name is used to avoid collision - use that name to read the file and delete it once you're done. Note also that your application will need read/write/delete access to the folder you will use for these operations.

You can find out more on how to access Excel file via OLEDB at [Connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)